# Vectors triangle problem.

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

Let D be the midpoint of the side BC of the triangle ABC

[image]

Verify that:

$$\vec{AD}=\tfrac12\big(\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}\big)$$

Comment: are you talking about length of AD, AB and AC or literally vector addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec {AD}$

$=\vec {AB}+\vec {BD}$

$=\vec {AB}+\frac12 \vec {BC}$

$=\vec {AB} +\frac12 (\vec {AC}-\vec {AB})$

$=\frac12 (\vec {AB}+\vec {AC})$

Comment: how'd you derive BD in your second line?